# Question about summing probabilities across multiple events

Tags: probability

So we've got an air freshener on a timer that sprays once every $36$ minutes (you can probably guess which room it's in).

If you're in the room on, say, ten different occasions, for $3.6$ minutes per visit, the probability of having the timer go off is $0.1$ on each occasion.

But what's the cumulative probability of having the timer go off across all ten visits--assuming that the visits are randomly distributed over a specified interval. And what would be a general formula?

Comment: This is not clear.  If the times are sufficiently randomized so that we can treat the events as independent then this is a standard binomial problem.  But is that the assumption you wanted to make?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for not making that clear. The distribution is random and over a longer specified interval. The general formula I'm looking for would take as inputs intervals of various lengths as well as the specified interval over which the smaller intervals are distributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that the timer doesn't go off during 1 visit: $1-0.1=0.9$. The probability that it doesn't go off $10$ times: $0.9^{10} = 0.35$. Which means it's a 65% chance that the timer goes off at least once. The general formula is:

$$P = 1 - (1-p)^n$$

where, $p$ is the probability that it goes off during one visit and $P$ is the total probability for $n$ visits.

Comment: Thanks! So if I'm understanding your response correctly, if the length of time varies (that is, it isn't always 3.6 minutes), the expression would be something along these lines: $P = 1 - (1 - p_1)(1 - p_2)...(1 - p_n)$, right?

Comment: Yep, that's right

Comment: Note though that this would only work if the order is strictly set. E.g. 3.6min, _then_ 7.2min. If you're interested in "there was one 3.6min and one 7.2min but it doesn't matter in which order", then it'd be more complicated - we'd have to add up probabilities of different combinations: 3.6 & 7.2 + 7.2 & 3.6

Comment: Can you explain why that is?

Comment: If your experiment (e.g. toss of a coin) can result in 2 mutually exclusive results (e.g. 0.8 for Tails, 0.2 for Heads), if you repeat it twice the probabilities can be described as $(0.8T + 0.2H)(0.8T + 0.2H)$. You can see all possibilities and their probabilities: $0.64T^2 + 2*0.16HT + 0.04H^2$. Where $T^2$ means two Tails in a row. While $HT$ is Heads, then Tails. Notice the factor of 2: $2*016HT$. This is because I din't care which one was first, so for me $HT$ and $TH$ were the same, and I could add them up. But if I _did_ care about the order, I'd end up with separate $0.16TH + 0.16HT$.